# how to reverse a string in java without charAt() method

Tags: recursion, reverse

i want to revers a string in java like name with recursive function java and i want to use without charat method

```
 public static void main(String args){

        String str = "yoosef";
        Log.i("log", "main: "+Reverst(str));

    }

    public static String Reverst(String r){
        String x = "";
        if(r.length()==0){
            return "your String is empth";

        }else if(r.length()>1){

            x= Reverst(r.substring(r.length()-1));
            if(x.length()>=r.length()) {
                return r;
            }
            //return Reverst(r.substring(r.length()-1));
        }
        return r;
    }
```

Comment: So what problem are you facing in your example?

Comment: You may want to use Apache StringUtils library reverse function. Please find Javadoc here https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html

Answer (score 1):

if you turn your `string` to charr array using `charArray` method and passe it to this function it will work fine without `charAt`

```
public void reverseString(char[] s) {
    int i=0;
    int j=s.length-1;
    while (i < j){
        char temp=s[i];
        s[i]=s[j];
        s[j]=temp;
        i++;
        j--;
        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class reverseString {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append("yoosef");

        sb.reverse();
        System.out.println(sb);

    }

}
```